# Fetch more than 1000 records from dynamic AX

Tags: mule, microsoft-dynamics, mule-studio

I am trying to fetch more than 1000 records from dynamic Ax using document service.But i am unable to fetch more than 1000 records.

We are using Mule esb to fetch the records from dynamic Ax using dynamic Ax connector.We have also tried by using static Query but we are getting  following error :

> Connection Reset(java.net.SocketException) invoking
>   https://10.10.1.23:9333/router :connection reset

When we test the connection in mule it gives test connection successful.

Is there any possible way to fetch thousands of record from dynamic Ax?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might need to tweak the settings on the Windows Gateway Services instance running on https://10.10.1.23:9333/router.

Specifically the AX connector related settings such as max buffer size and max received message size. The settings are tweaked in the config file of the service called Mule.SelfHost.exe.config, which should reside in the installation directory. After tweaking remember to restart the service!

See this guide for more details:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/windows-gateway-services-guide#configuring-dynamics-crm-and-ax-connector-settings